# CSS triangle-like notch cut out of responsive div with text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a CSS solution to have a triangle-like notch cut out of a div that is responsive like the one pictured below.

[image]

The div will have content in it and I want this to be responsive, so as there is more text, or the browser is made smaller the notch will grow with the container. I have seen responsive arrows made with CSS before like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3HG6d/2943/), but I'm not sure how change the angle of the triangle and implement it into my div. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.triangle-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    padding-left: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-right:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    margin-top:-500px;
    margin-left: -500px;
     
    border-top: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid transparent;
    border-left: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
<div class="triangle-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @BobRodes for getting me set in the right direction! 
I took your example and added jQuery to take the height of the div, divide it by 2 to have the values of the top and bottom borders. If the height of the div is not a whole number, then the border height is a fraction and the notch came up 1px short, so I took that into consideration and accounted for that by adding 1px in that case. I also noticed in Firefox and IE, sometimes the border was too tall (Browser rendering maybe?) and the notch hung below the content div by 1px. Chrome seemed to be fine. To get around all of this, I reversed the notch so that it was pointing to the right and made this the same color as the background color. Now if I have a 1px overhang, it will never be visible. 
If I wrap my jQuery in a function and call that on resize, this is completely responsive and works with any amount of content.
Here is my code:

```js
//find the height of the content div and use 50% of the height for the border height to create the notch
var ContentHeight = $('.Content').outerHeight(),
  BorderHeight = ContentHeight / 2,
  //we'll assume that the border-top and border-bottom will be the same, but we may need to make a tweak below
  BorderHeight2 = BorderHeight;

//if 1/2 the height of the content is a fraction, the border will be 1px short. We'll add 1px to the bottom to compensate 
if (ContentHeight % 2 === 1) {
  BorderHeight2++;
}
//add the border to create the notch
$('.Notch').css({
  'border-top': BorderHeight + 'px solid transparent',
  'border-bottom': BorderHeight2 + 'px solid transparent'
});
```

```css
.Wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
}
.Notch {
  border-left: 15px solid #fff;
  left: -8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.Content {
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, #055aa5 0%, #227dcd 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  left: -8px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="Notch"></div>
  <div class="Content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi.</p>
    <p>Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works a bit differently from your example, using border values. You put one div for the notch, and put your regular div next to it.  This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="notch">
    </div>
    <div class="content" >
        <label>Here is the content</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
div.container {
    position:relative;
}

div.notch, div.content {
    position:absolute;
}

div.notch {
    border-top: 20px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

div.content {
    left: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

You should be able to tinker with these basic values and alter things. You change the angle by altering the width of the left border relative to the top and bottom borders.  The `left` in the content div must match the `border-left-width` in the notch div.

There are some other ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475313/css-triangle-to-fit-variable-sized-div-elements?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not responsive. If I add more content to the div, the notch doesn't grow with it. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/867n69jp/

Comment: I think I might need some clarification on your definition of "responsive."  If you are saying that you want the notch to automatically resize as a function of the CSS styling, when you alter the number of lines in the content, rather than resizing them by changing the CSS values yourself, then no, this won't fit that definition.  In that case, you'd have to do it through code, by evaluating the height of the content box and setting the size of the top and bottom borders to half of it.  In your fiddle, setting the borders to 76px does the trick.